# Django tastypie and posting related data using FormsValidation

Tags: tastypie

I have a weird problem when posting data to the invoice resource. If product validation fails Invoice is still saved without failed product data.

What I want is that invoice is not saved until all products are validated.

Do I need to handle products validation in invoice resource somehow or can tastypie handle this automatically?

Below the code....

models.py

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    some_model_fields

class Product(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    some_model_fields
```

and forms.py

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ['invoice']

class InvoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
```

and resources.py

```
class ProductResource(ModelResource):
    invoice = fields.ForeignKey('apps.api.InvoiceResource', 'invoice')

class Meta:
    resource_name = 'product'
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    validation = FormValidation(form_class=ProductForm)

class InvoiceResource(ModelResource):
    products = fields.ToManyField(ProductResource,
                              'product_set',
                              related_name='invoice',
                              null=False,
                              full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'invoice'
        always_return_data = True
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=InvoiceForm)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Not the way I liked. I am calling product and invoice with separate requests, first saving product and then adding invoices to the product with separate call.